# How to use Radio Button in Repeater to retrieve data from sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I am using Radio Buttons in Repeater but in C# Function i can't get the ID of that Radio Button:

[image]

This Asp code Radio buttons with group in Repeater:

[image]

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            RadioButton1.Text = dr.GetString(5);
            RadioButton2.Text = dr.GetString(6);
            RadioButton3.Text = dr.GetString(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please remove images and post text code.

Answer (score 0):

As you know your RadioButtns are in Repeater, so you have to set these buttons text from Repeater using `Foreach` loop as:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
   // Check for data item or alternating item
   if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
       // find your radiobutton from repeater's item
       RadioButton RadioButton1 = item.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;

       RadioButton1.Text = dr.GetString(5);

       //.. some other code
   }
}
```